# Bold a single line in html table <td>

Tags: html, css

I have used the following code to make a table but in the  tag i only need the XYZ to be bold and all others to be unbold. But when I used this code the whole  is going bold. I don't wish to use a css style sheet with this file. Someone please tell me how I can achieve this.

```
<table width=100%>
<tr>
<td><center><b>XYZ<b><br>Aabc<br>+91-xxxxxxxxx<br>xyz@htjkl.com<center></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You should use a style sheet.
2. There is a simple typo: The / is missing in the second occurrence of `<b>`.

Comment: To clarify, @Oskar is saying you need to close your tags. `<b>XYZ</b>`, and your center `</center>`

Answer (score 9):

```
<table style='width:100%;'>
    <tr>
        <td style='text-align:center;'>
            <span style='font-weight:bold;'>XYZ</span><br>
            Aabc<br>
            +91-xxxxxxxxx<br>
            xyz@htjkl.com</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n5WZt/

Answer (score 5):

please close your all tag

```
<table width=100%>
<tr height=11%>
<td><center><b>XYZ</b><br>Aabc<br>+91-xxxxxxxxx<br>xyz@htjkl.com</center></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You got wrong spelling in HTML tag, close b tag forgot /, try this:

```
<table width=100%>
  <tr>
    <td><center><b>XYZ</b><br>Aabc<br>+91-xxxxxxxxx<br>xyz@htjkl.com<center></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```