# Make contents of a table or td tag bold

Tags: javascript, html, css, yahoo-api

I'm working with some legacy code and encountered the following issue.

I'm using YAHOO.widget.DataTable( elContainer, aColumnDefs, oDataSource, oConfigs ) structure to modify html elements in a table.

I am running a basic number to US currency conversion on the code in one td of this table. It works for other tables however it fails in this table because all elements are set to bold via the "< \b >" tag which is being pulled into the Yahoo Table structure as the td value.

Ex:

```
<td>
    <b><s:property value="totalTransactions"/> my text </b>
</td>
```

For example when the table queries the value at this td it gets 
`"<b><s:property value="totalTransactions"/> my text</b>".` When really all I want is *my text*.

My preffered solution is to remove the b tags.

So the code can run (and doesn't need to differ between different tables and it doesn't need to clean them all first and then attempt to distinguish when it should add bold tags back)

For example I could check if html exists remove it, modify the number, and then add the html back. I think it's cleaner (personal preference perhaps) to modify the table so that it keeps the bold font for all elements in it without adding text inside the td tag.

I looked at: [Bold a single line in html table <td>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811351/bold-a-single-line-in-html-table-td)

I tried

```
<td style="font-weight:bold"> my text </td>
```

However it does not become bold.

the bold tag makes the text bold when done like this:

```
<td>
    <b>my text</b>
</td>
```

However the b tag interferes with my function. My thought that is due to the yahoo injection:

```
result =  "$"+myAmount;
el.innerHTML = result;
```

That the bold style might be overwritten. Are there any solutions? Or is there another reason style doesn't work?

I believe the issue is due to the fact that I'm using a struct: see http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-property-tag-example/ .

I am unsure of why traditional styling rules do not apply. Or perhaps I have made an error? The page renders fine just without any bold. I see no logged errors.

Comment: You are first saying that something fails because some content is bold, and then you are asking how to make it bold. This does not make any sense.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I'm saying its failing because it's pulling in the bold tag. I want to make it bold without using html <b> (which was answered below)

Comment: “It’s pulling in the bold tag” makes no sense. What “it”? “Pulling in” in what sense? You should most probably fix the function that does not handle the actual markup used, instead of tweaking the markup.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela it as in the the yahoo table i mentioned above: http://zottmann.org/yuidoc-theme-dana-example/YAHOO.widget.DataTable.html which then calls the function on my text

Comment: and yeah i think ill have to change the method and leave the html

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood form your question there are 2 possible solutions with inline css.

First one

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    table td {
        font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table><tr><td>Text inside table cell</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Second one

```
<table>
    <tr><td style="font-weight:bold">Text inside the table</td></tr>
</table>
```

one with css declaration:

```
table td {
            font-weight:bold;
        }
```

Another solution will be using strong tag to wrap the text.

```
<table><tr><td><strong>Text goes here</strong></td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood the question correctly and your goal is to bold all text in one table. 
This inline style makes all texts in the cells from the table bold:

```
<table style="font-weight: 700;">...
```

or a more readable version:

```
<table style="font-weight: bold;">...
```

Comment: `bold` means `700` by definition. Not that it would make any difference in most situations in practice, but if you mention the number at all, make sure it is the right number.

Answer (score 0):

While the other two answer at the moment have covered the basics, using either strong tag or using a css style (inline or in a style dec).

If the above two still fail, perhaps another means would be using javascript or jquery to enumerate over the table and apply a bold style afterwards either directly to each td cell or table by applying a css or inserting your own b/strong tags.

This may not be an option in your case, but being others will see this. There are still times when this is called for.

I wont post any code as the basics are covered, unless you need a Javascript/jQuery code.

Comment: I think the issue has to do with using a struct in combination with yahoo table properties. Hm... I'm not sure that jquery will go over the table after my javascript modification occurs.

Comment: Being i'm more familiar with js and jquery, not YUI.. I just did a quick jsfiddle to play around.. Using http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/datatable-paginator.html i quickly did a mock up and noticed the option 'className' which got me thinking. Firstly can you host a quick jsfiddle simulating your issue, secondly.. what about having a pre-defined css class and then in some way trigger those td's to apply the class name to them selves?  might not make much sense, But using a TD's attribute tag instead to trigger it being bold or not.. As its easier to control and alot safer